# Could not start new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I'm using selenium IE Driver 4.7 to run code on Microsoft edge in IE mode. Code run successfully but when we disconnect from server then after some intervals of time there is an error comes as "Error communicating with the remote browser.It may have died." After that when BOT runs same code then captions error occurred (could not session).But same code work in IE after server disconnect also.

Sample code for calling edge in IE mode,

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "IE Driver Path"); InternetExplorerOptions ieOptions = new InternetExplorerOptions();

ieOptions.attachToEdgeChrome ();

ieOptions.ignore ZoomSettings ();

ieOptions.withEdgeExecutable Path ("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe");

driver = new InternetExplorerDriver (ieOptions);

driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();

driver.manage () .window () .maximize();

driver.get("https://www.finacle.com");
```

Help me out to sort out this issue.

I also tried selenium IE Driver 4.2 version but not worked. Current selenium jar version is 4.2.2.

I'm need java selenium code (for automation on ie) to be run in IE mode on ms edge without facing mentioned error due server disconnected.

Comment: I've tried both IE Driver 4.2 and 4.7 but I can't reproduce this issue. How did you disconnect from server? Is the sample code you've provided enough to reproduce the issue? If not, please provide minimal reproducible code for us. Also, you can try the latest version of IEDriverServer, which is 4.8.0.

Comment: Code is working fine on IE browser even if disconnect from server (RPA process is deployed there) but I had changed browser calling code in IE mode on edge.Mentioned code is for reference.If you have any idea why above error occurred or if any another code for IE mode in edge please share.

Answer (score 0):

As common solutions regarding this error, I suggest

1. **Kill all the IEDriverServer.exe** and then you can test again.
2. Make sure that you've closed/quitted the driver every time before the automation ends.

Since it works in IE while fails in IE mode, it can also be related to the **timeout error** in IE mode automation. 2 solutions to this are:

1. Turn off protected mode of each zone in Internet Options
2. Use `InitialBrowserUrl` to directly visit the desired page, without waiting for redirection which could cause timeout error. Example: `ieOptions.InitialBrowserUrl = "https://www.bing.com";`

Comment: Thanks for solutions but it's not working.Do we need to change any server level settings for automation (on MS Edge in IE mode).

Comment: @ChhaganChavan Then it can be related to your server environment. Haven't seen this issue before. You may need to contact the Selenium Team [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues) and provide more information for troubleshooting.